# How to let Jmeter Http request sampler preload and resue the upload file in its upload test?

Tags: upload, jmeter

In JMeter's Http Request sampler, I can define the filePath for the request to upload, but when I run the load test, each test repeatedly load the same file.  Because it loads the file from disk each time the time to finish each test is much longer than the real time that server takes to return the response.

Do I have to write my sampler to  preload the file to memory before the test and reuse the file when it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can preload the file using BeanShell sampler and store its value in single variable once. But the problem is you can't share variables between threads. So, once read and stored as variable, it can be only used in the same thread.

To share parameters between threads, it's possible to use properties, but not sure that you can do the same with files as they contain binaries.

Talking about regular variables (for example, cookies), that's how it can be done:

1. Read the variable from file withing setUp thread.
2. Define this value as a property.
3. Use the value stored in property in all your HTTP samplers.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're trying to do. If you give it a hard-coded path, it will always upload that file. If you're trying to generate load on an upload endpoint, as long as this hard-coded file is roughly the size you'd expect, that should be fine.

If you're trying to get JMeter to upload a set of files, you're going to have to get a little fancy. I would save all of the paths of the files you want uploaded as strings in a `CSV`. Then use a `CSV Data Set` to save it to a variable `path`. Then instead of giving that path hard-coded to your `HTTP Request Sampler`, give it `${path}`. Loop your test `n` times (where `n` is the number of files you put in your CSV) and that should do it.

Comment: I see that my question is not so clear, actually I am using a variable like you suggested; What I really want is let the sampler use the data in memory but not load it from disk in each test so that the time to finish the whole test could be much shorter. I edited my question.